# Error Docmd.Import Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

Hola a todos una vez mas,

Tengo un formulario con origen de datos a mi tabla tblDatos y en el mismo formulario un cuadro de lista y un textbox. Lo que hago es realizar la busqueda de un codigo de cliente sobre el formulario y si encuentra el codigo de cliente lo agrego al cuadro de lista. Hasta aqui todo bien.

Ahora pretendo importar de un archivo Excel en una ruta especifica todos los nombres de las hojas coincidentes con el cuadro de lista.

Hasta hoy no habia tenido problemas con importaciones de Excel hacia Access con Docmd.transfer

Pero estoy probando importar con el siguiente codigo:

```
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TblRecetas", PathFileName, False, "Sheet2"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "Import Complete"
```

Per me devuelve error 3011 la hoja dos no existe, pero si voy a Excel esta si existe, cabe mencionar que estoy probando la importación hoja por hoja, aun no tengo idea de como recorrer el listbox y buscar las coincidentes con el archivo Excel en question e importalas.

A que se debe este error?
Si hago la importacion manual de la hoja dos lo hace sin problemas.

Agrego, parte del codigo, que pretendo usar para recorrer el listbox y pasar el valor al parametro de importacion.

> ```
> Do While Me.lstImport.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 '<-- No me hace el recorrido, entra a un bucle infinito
> DoCmd.SetWarnings False
> Debug.Print PathFileName
> DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TblRecetas", PathFileName, True, "4211134!A:G" '<-- En esta ultima
> ```
>
> linea pasar el nombre tomado
>       DoCmd.SetWarnings True
>       Loop
>       MsgBox "Import Complete

Espero me puedan ayudar.

DS

P

Comment: Puede ser que tu hoja no se llame "Sheet2" y haya cambiado de nombre?

Comment: @Damian
Es correcto el nombre visual de la hoja es otro ejemplo: 3497901, pero internamente si entras a vba de Excel puedes ver el nombre de la hoja (Index)
He realizado un ligero cambio agregando el rango a importar y asi si me importa la hoja:
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TblRecetas", PathFileName, True, "3497901!A:G"

Ahora como paso el Item (nombre de la hoja) cargadas en de un listbox en access al parametro de importación.

Comment: añades un argumento a tu función que sea `NombreHoja` por ejemplo y al llamar a esa función le das el nombre de la hoja necesaria Jose.

Comment: @Damian
Creo que lo que mencionas es interactuar Excel directamente, no es asi?
Lo que quiero dar a entender que que los nombres de las hojas que quiero importar las cargo en un listbox, entonces quiero recorrer ese listbox desde el  inicio y pasar el primer valor al parametro de importacion y asi consecuentemente hasta terminar de recorrer todas las hojas del listbox y todas las importaciones.

Comment: @Damian
Edite la pregunta y agregue el codigo que estoy probando.

Comment: Si estás añadiendo valores en tiempo de ejecución, la propiedad `RowSource` te debería devolver la lista de items, separados por punto y coma. Te puedes llevar eso a una matriz con un `Split` y recorrer la matriz. Respecto al error del nombre de la hoja, no es lo mismo la propiedad `CodeName` (lo que vemos en el editor de VBA como Hoja1,Hoja2, etc) que `Name` (el nombre que visualmente vemos en Excel, en la pestaña inferior)